# Validação para TextArea utilizando Razor MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho o seguinte modal e preciso incluir validações para que o `textarea` seja obrigatório ao clicar no botão "Sim", ou seja, não pode ser enviado em branco, e para que o `textarea` tenha no mínimo 15 caracteres.

```
  @model TClient
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              @using (Html.BeginForm())
              {
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">@(Model.IsLocked ? "Desbloquear" : "Bloquear") cliente</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Deseja realmente @(Model.IsLocked ? "desbloquear" : "bloquear") o cliente <strong>@Model.Name</strong>?</p>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <hr />
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label">
                                      Motivo:
                                  </label>
                                  <div>
                                      @this.TextArea("motivo").Class("form-control required").Rows(7).Columns(50)
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                          Não
                      </button>
                      <button type="submit" id="confirmar" class="btn btn-primary">
                          Sim
                      </button>
                  </div>
              }
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Está usando jQuery.Validate?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Acredito que sim, pois existem várias validações na aplicação que trabalho em javascript, jquery, etc. Qual seria sua proposta para as questões? Pois não encontrei nada a respeito até o momento

Comment: Eu não entendi o que é isto aqui: `@this.TextArea("motivo").Class("form-control required").Rows(7).Columns(50)`. Pode editar sua pergunta com o código fonte desses métodos?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é onde eu crio o TextArea com Razor, em MVC 4

Answer (score 1):

Não consigo ver esta abordagem bem:

```
@model TClient

...

@this.TextArea("motivo").Class("form-control required").Rows(7).Columns(50)
```

O correto seria tipar fortemente a *View*:

```
@model MeuSistema.Models.MeuModel
```

E usar o seguinte clichê:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Motivo, new { @class = "form-control required", @cols = 50, @rows = 7 })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Motivo)
```

Se você decorou o *Model* corretamente:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public String Motivo { get; set; }
```

E o jQuery.Validate está instalado corretamente, deve funcionar sem mais configurações. Ainda, você pode forçar a validação do formulário da seguinte forma (jQuery):

```
$('#botaoSubmit').on('click', function() {
    $("#form").valid();
});
```